# Why width is not working in form and submit button too

Tags: java, html, css, user-interface

```css
#side-bottom{}
      #side-bottom h3{
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 20px;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   }
   #side-bottom form{}
     #side-bottom form input{type='email'}
  {
           width: 200px;
           height: 20px;       
}
     #side-bottom form input{type="submit" value="submit"}{
        width: 200px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     height: 30px;
     background:#FF9900;
     }
```

```html
</section>
<aside>
     <div id="side-top">
        <h1>Latest post</h1>
        <div id="latest-post-list">
         <div class="latest-post"> First post title</div>
         <div class="latest-post"> First post title</div>
         <div class="latest-post"> First post title</div>
         <div class="latest-post"> First post title</div>
    </div>
</div>
      <div id="side-bottom">
      <h3>News updates</h3>
       <form>
        <input type="text" name="email">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
</div>
```

Here in htmlside, when is used form code in that input submit button is not working properly and in css side width is not working i m unable to get it, whats wrong here to activate it.

Comment: Invalid CSS syntax: replace `{type='email'}` by `[type="email"]` and `{type="submit" value="submit"}` by `[type="submit"][value="submit"]`. What do you mean by “submit button is not working properly”?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple syntax errors.

For example, there is a space between `input` and the attribute `[type="submit"]` (there should be none - see code below)

Also, there is no element of `[type="email"]` (it should be either `[type="text"]` or `[name="email"]`

and many more...

I have fixed some of the issues in the code below but I am not sure what you desired outcome is.

```css
#side-bottom h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
#side-bottom form input {
  width: 200px;
}
#side-bottom form input[name='email'] {
  height: 20px;
}
#side-bottom form input[type="submit"] {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #FF9900;
}
```

```html
<div id="side-top">
  <h1>Latest post</h1>
  <div id="latest-post-list">
    <div class="latest-post">First post title</div>
    <div class="latest-post">First post title</div>
    <div class="latest-post">First post title</div>
    <div class="latest-post">First post title</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="side-bottom">
  <h3>News updates</h3>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```